# Mlogit for Rank-Ordered Logit - Troubleshooting

Tags: r, mlogit

I am trying to use the mlogit package to run a rank-ordered logit on my data. I had participants choose their top three out of 24 choices, and then rank them in order of preference. When I try to prepare the data for analysis using the mlogit.data command, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in rep(k, Z) : invalid 'times' argument
```

I am wondering if the error has to do with rank ties. Out of 24 alternatives, participants only ranked 3, leaving the rest blank. I have since replaced the blanks with 4s. My data looks like the following:

```
head(t)

id ch.1 ch.2 ch.3 ch.4 ch.5 ch.6 ch.7 ch.8 ch.9 ch.10 ch.11 ch.12 ch.13
1    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     4     4     2
2    4    4    4    4    4    2    4    4    4     4     4     3     4
3    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     2     4     4
4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    1    4     4     4     4     2
5    4    4    4    4    1    4    4    4    4     4     4     4     3
6    3    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    2     4     4     4     4
ch.14 ch.15 ch.16 ch.17 ch.18 ch.19 ch.20 ch.21 ch.22 ch.23 ch.24 
4    4     4     4     1     4     4     4     4     3     4      
4    4     4     4     4     4     4     1     4     4     4      
4    4     4     4     4     4     4     3     4     1     4      
4    4     3     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4      
4    4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     2     4      
4    4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     1     4      
gender condition
0      0
1      0
0      1
1      1 
0      0
1      1
```

Code for reproducible example:

```
ch.1 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.2 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.3 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.4 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 4, 2)
ch.5 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.6 <- c(4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.7 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.8 <- c(4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
2, 4, 1, 4)
ch.9 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.10 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.11 <- c(4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.12 <- c(4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 3)
ch.13 <- c(2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
3, 4, 4, 4) 
ch.14 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.15 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.16 <- c(4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.17 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.18 <- c(1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 
1, 4, 4, 4)
ch.19 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.20 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
4, 1, 4, 4)
ch.21 <- c(4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 3, 4)
ch.22 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
ch.23 <- c(3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1, 
4, 2, 2, 1)
ch.24 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4)
gender <- sample(c(0,1), 24, replace=T)
condition <- sample(c(0,1), 24, replace=T)
t <- cbind(ch.1, ch.2, ch.3, ch.4, ch.5, ch.6, ch.7, ch.8, ch.9, ch.10, 
ch.11, ch.12, ch.13, ch.14, ch.15, ch.16, ch.17, ch.18, ch.19, ch.20,
ch.21, ch.22, ch.23, ch.24, gender, condition)
t <- as.data.frame(t)
G <- mlogit.data(t, shape="wide", choice="ch", varying=1:24, ranked=TRUE)

Error in rep(k, Z) : invalid 'times' argument
```

Thanks for any insight you can provide, and if mlogit can't handle this data, does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

letitburn,

-- quite sure that the issue are ties at the bottom. You have probably discovered by now Stata's "rologit" routine for rank-ordered data. It can handle these types of  incomplete rankings.